# ожидание выполнения коррутины и возврат результата в UI

Tags: android, kotlin

Пытаюсь выполнить загрузку модели в корутине и нарисовать результат в `ImageView`. Выполнить рисование в корутине невозможно, так как создается другой поток, если попытаться рисовать после выполнения корутины, то нет ожидания выполнения корутины и рисуется белый `ImageView`. Как дождаться выполнения корутины, получить результат и продолжить выполнение кода в главном потоке?

```
fun someFun() {
    GlobalScope.launch {

        val downloadModel: MDownloadingFragment
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        downloadModel = MDownloadingFragment()
        downloadModel.show(fragmentManager, "DOWNLFRAGMENT")

        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(documentUri)!!
        val model = getModel(inputStream)
        stlModel = model.await()
        downloadModel.dismiss()

        }
    setImage(graph(stlModel))
}

fun getModel(inputStream: InputStream) =
    GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { parseModel(inputStream) }// suspend fun parseModel 
}
```

Comment: можете использовать `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { ... }` внутри корутины, чтобы выполнить код на главном потоке https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html

Comment: Main и есть ui? Тут противоречивые требования) надо и ui не заблочить и во вью вернуть. Я так понимаю что коррутины не используют нативные потоки как таковые

Comment: Вообщем Main все равно блочит хоть и не UI, рисовать все равно не дает

Comment: во ViewModel записывайте результат в MutableLiveData и подписывайтесь на нее в ui

Comment: коррутины мимо кассы? или я чет не понимаю?

Comment: выполняете работу в корутине и результат записываете в MutableLiveData. например imageData.postValue(it) вот пример: https://medium.com/ruangguru-engineering/how-to-coroutine-livedata-in-viewmodel-6def66f932a7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете переключаться внутри корутины на разные Dispatcher. Вот вам небольшой пример:

```
private var viewModelJob = Job()
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

uiScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                //Do background tasks...
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    //Update UI
                }
            }
        }
```

Так же неплохо описана работа с корутинами в [документации](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines).

А вот [здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/kotlin/29-course/kotlin/594-urok-1-vvedenie.html) вы можете найти очень хорошие уроки по корутинам.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Проще чем с liveData))

Comment: Но тем не менее, я вам все же рекомендую ознакомится как работать с LiveData. Это

Comment: Да вкрации почитал, хотел потыкать корутины, получается livedata действительно интересная вещь при  написании мэссенджеров?

Comment: У меня тут есть один учебный проектик. Можете посмотреть, там как раз есть и корутины и лайв дата https://github.com/industradamus/TheMovie

Comment: Уже наткнулся, но сегодня уже хватит). Тоже пишу приложения и учиться и с практическим применением))

Comment: https://github.com/Veilvi мой хаб, конечно не густо, но я меньше года пишу

Comment: @killbit, корутины и LiveData это как бы разного поля ягоды. Могут расти вместе и по отдельности, один другому не мешая и не заменяя.

Comment: Да я это понял, в моем то случае корутины достаточно. Livedata хорошо для обмена информацией в режиме реального времени. Но чую до этого еще доберусь